# Is it possible to add an OnScrollListener to a Android Spinner?

Tags: android

Is is possible to append new set data for android spinner when last index is reached? so i'm thinking i can implement a onScrollListener for spinner.

Comment: you can refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668042/onscrolllistener-not-working-inside-custom-listview-adapter) for solution..

Comment: Thank you for your time but i already found a way to solve my problem.